# Calculating $-\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \left[\ln\left(\frac{1}{1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}} \right)\right].$

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble computing the following partial derivative:

$$-\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \left[\ln\left(\frac{1}{1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}} \right)\right]$$

Here, $\beta$ is what I am differentiating with respect to. Also, $\hbar$ and $\omega$ are just constants (so the final answer will still have those terms). The final answer is

$$\frac{\hbar\omega e^{-\beta\hbar\omega}}{1 - e^{-\beta\hbar\omega}};$$

but, I'm having difficulty getting this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$-\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \left[\ln\left(\frac{1}{1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}} \right)\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \left[\ln\left({1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}} \right)\right]=\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \left({1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}} \right)}{1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega} }=\cdots ???$$